# Can I download an image from fandom?

Tags: internet

The image I want to get is from fandom and it's from a movie (a promotional image) so I'm wondering if I can *legally* do it. I would prefer a yes or no answer.

Comment: To clarify or confirm: is this http://fandom.com?

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can download the image.

If you are asking this question you are obviously referring to copyrights and therefore should just have the sense to know that you can't use a copyrighted image without permission though.